# Running Emacs as a client does not load my settings

Tags: emacsclient, emacs-daemon, daemon

I'm using the new systemd daemon option with Emacs 26. I have a problem, though. If I open a client instance (`emacsclient -c`) no config files (my `.emacs`) are loaded. So I don't see the usefulness in running Emacs as a client.
Can somebody cast some light on this?

Comment: How do you start the emacs server?

Comment: Systemd starts it. I have created a service that starts it at boot. I followed Emacs 26's documentation: `systemctl --user enable emacs`. The service runs Emacs daemon with the command: `/usr/bin/emacs --daemon`.

Comment: What user is running the daemon?

Comment: I myself, I imagine, as the service is created userwise.